# UCanAccess driver not found when converted to JAR file

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I made a project named clinic which has 3 jframes

1. login
2. clinic management
3. generate patient ID

It is connected to an Access database (.mdb).

I converted it to JAR file but it gives me error that it is not getting connected to the UCanAccess driver.

I even tried SQLite manager but had the same problem.
I am using netbeans 8.
I just directly selected clean and build option to make the jar file.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please check the [FAQ - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. Your question is missing some information to get a good answer, such what are the exact error messages and the stack trace, if available.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Eclipse, NetBeans does not offer a standard way to Export a Java project to a single runnable JAR file that contains all of the project's dependencies. Instead, when you Build a Java project in NetBeans it creates a `\dist` folder that contains

- the JAR file for your own Java code, plus
- a `\lib` subfolder containing the JAR files for the dependencies.

When you distribute your Java project to other users, [Packaging and Deploying Desktop Java Applications](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html) says that you need to

> 1. Create a zip file that contains the application JAR file (`YourStuff.jar`) and the accompanying `lib` folder that contains [the additional jar files that your application requires].
> 2. Send the file to the people who will use the application. Instruct them to unpack the zip file, making sure that the main application jar file and the `lib` folder are in the same folder. The users of your application should be able to run it by double-clicking the JAR file.

For example, when I unpack the zip file for my test application I have

```
[C:\__tmp]
    README.TXT
    UCanAccessDemo.jar
    [\lib]
        commons-lang-2.6.jar
        commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
        hsqldb.jar
        jackcess-2.0.6.jar
        ucanaccess-2.0.9.2.jar
```

A quick web search revealed at least one mechanism that claims to allow NetBeans to create a single monolithic JAR file that includes dependencies ...

[PackagingADistributableJavaApp](http://wiki.netbeans.org/PackagingADistributableJavaApp)

... but I have not tried it myself. (I just get Eclipse to do it.)

Comment: I also found this to be true, but is there any way to force netbeans to do it properly? User-end problems occur when there is a lib folder involved

Answer (score 1):

Do you have export lib files within .jar file?
There are some dependency classes which are required to connect to database which also need to be included with .jar file, or you can copy all required dependency to folder named as `lib` in same folder where your .jar file exist.